# I can't create new fields of type image

Tags: media, 10

Drupal v10.2+ has that new shiny admin UI for creating new fields. However, that new shiny page does not allow the creation of new image fields (the non-reuseable image files, NOT the reuseable media entity image bundle).

When visiting that page, I see the option "Media" (don't want that), "File upload" (this is plain file upload without image processing capabilities) and "Reference". Reference has sub options for "Content", "User", "Taxonomy term" and "Other", but once again no plain image fields. The "Other" option then lists all config entity types and all content entity types (including media entities and file fields), but no image fields.

So I can not create new image fields anywhere.

OTOH, the media entity bundle "image" still has the field "field_media_image" of type "Image", so it is there somehow.

I feel I'm missing something obvious, a new config setting maybe? How can I create new image fields in Drupal v10.2+ ?

Comment: File upload has the option File or Image.

Comment: errr.... no it hasn't for me ?

Comment: It's loaded via Ajax once you select it.

Comment: OK, got the issue. You have to enter the field name FIRST, and only then the ajax selection for image upload appears.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a small bug in core as of v10.2.2

In the english UI, all works OK.

But when using a translated admin UI (my primary interface language is german), you have to enter a field name FIRST (this is important), and THEN select "File upload", and then the image field option appears below.

Comment: See core issue https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3415799